# This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that Play Integrity checks, and reCAPTCHA checks were unsuccessful. No solution

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-play

The error is  This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that Play Integrity checks, and reCAPTCHA checks were unsuccessful

I am trying to implement Play Integrity check and remove safetynet. I have followed everything but I have failed.

```
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
    webProvider: ReCaptchaV3Provider('recaptcha-v3-site-key'),
    androidProvider: AndroidProvider.playIntegrity,
    appleProvider: AppleProvider.appAttest,
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
  
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.6.0"))
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:integrity:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'
}

sendOtp() async{
    await firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: widget.userPhoneNumber!,
      verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
        pinController.setText(credential.smsCode!);
      },

      verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
        debugPrint("Error ${e.toString()}");
        debugPrint("Error ${e.message}");
        if (e.code == 'invalid-phone-number') {
          debugPrint('The provided phone number is not valid.');
        }

      },

      codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) {
        verifyId = verificationId;
        resendTokenForOtp = resendToken ?? 0;
      },

      timeout: const Duration(seconds: 25),
      forceResendingToken: resendTokenForOtp,


      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {},
    );
  }
```